# What is the type of {object}?

Tags: c++

Consider following piece of code:

```
void foo (M&) {}

M m;
foo ({m});
```

So, the expression `{m}` is treated as rvalue reference and that is why this code fails to compile.

**Is this true that `{object}` always produces temporary object?**

If no, then how to be sure when it happens?
If yes, please consider following code:

```
struct M {};

struct I {
    I (M&) {}
};

struct MM {
    MM (M& p)
    : m (p), i ( {p} )
    {}

    M& m;
    I i;
};

M m;
MM mm {m};
```

Here there is no problem at all, so what is the difference between `{m}` from the first example and `{p}` from the second?

Compiler (GCC 4.8.1) results (first example):

```
main.cpp:366:13: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘M&’ from an rvalue of type ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’
     foo ({m});
             ^
main.cpp:359:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void foo(M&)’
 void foo (M&) {}
```

Comment: What compiler error did you get, and with which compiler? Maybe post a [mcve]?

Comment: @juanchopanza I would bet `invalid initialization of non-const ref of type T1 from rvalue of type T2`

Comment: @Bathsheba Missing [mcve]. Can't reproduce on g++ or clang.

Comment: if want to see whats going on, i suggest you could do sth like that: `clang-check -ast-dump tmp.cpp -- -std=c++11`. there you can investigate how the compiler sees ur code. the double dash is required!

Comment: g++ from 4.9 and clang from 3.1 accepts it, the older one rejects

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Really? I thought `{m}` was a *braced-init-list* which could be converted to a `std::initializer_list` in some situations, but not this one.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's a common misconception. The type of `{x}` depends on its context. If you pass it to a function which has an overload taking a `std::initialiser_list`, then yes it will match that overload and that will be its type. But if not, it won't, and no temporary `std::initialiser_list` will be created (not even a theoretical one that can get elided away).

Comment: After a little testing I would say it's a bug with your current (and *old*) compiler. The version 4 series of GCC didn't have a full C++11 implementation, and it's likely that this is the problem here. If you use a later version both snippets you show should work fine.

Comment: The argument is initializer for the parameter, it should behave like  `M &arg {m};` which is legal. gcc 4.8 was bugged with initiailzation of references from object of the same type

Comment: It's [bug PR#56976](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56976), it's fixed in g++4.9

Comment: it's the infamous [DR 1288](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288) - it was a bug in the C++11 spec, g++ 4.8 followed the spec, clang did what was sensible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the type of `{object}`?

That depends on the context. In some situations, such as when constructing a type with a `std::initializer_list` parameter, it'll be of type `std::initializer_list<decltype(object)>`. In others, it'll be used to initialize members of an aggregate or some other type, in which case the syntactic form `{object}` doesn't *have* a type *per se*.

> Is this true that `{object}` always produces temporary object?

No, and in your case it shouldn't. This was [a bug in the C++11 spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1288) relating to the ordering of clauses specifying list initialization. The old wording meant that your call resulted in the construction of a temporary (which is ill-formed due to the non-const reference parameter), but under the new rules, the reference binds to the single initializer list element. Your old compiler implements the old wording, whereas [newer compilers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39564c68854632dd) implement the fixed behaviour.

> Here there is no problem at all, so what is the difference between {m} from the first example and {p} from the second?

The difference is that `{m}` is used to initialize the `M` parameter of `foo` (invalid under the old wording), but `{p}` initializes the `I` member. As such, `p` is taken as the argument to the `I` constructor, binds to the `M&` parameter, and since `p` is an lvalue, everything is fine and dandy.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this true that {object} always produces temporary object?

No (read on).

Both snippets are valid (you should use an up-to-date compiler) and will compile successfully.

The `{p}` case falls into `[over.match.list]/p1`

> When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized such that [dcl.init.list] specifies that overload resolution is performed according to the rules in this section, overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> (1.1)
>   Initially, the candidate functions are the initializer-list constructors ([dcl.init.list]) of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument.
>
> **(1.2)**
>   If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list.

Specifically in (1.2), while `{m}` is a list initialization for the other case.